# i can't see the vertices after applying jmesh tools

Tags: vertices

I have recently started using the blender and obviously I have problems that I cannot solve ...
When I apply the jmesh tools and go into edit mode it only shows me the vertices and the faces[image] that are in the first section of the cylinder I created and if I try to move a vertex it is not even connected to each other.
If anyone can help me I would be very grateful. Thank you[image]

Comment: i found why....i have to apply the modifier!

Comment: applying the modifier the vertices and faces connected. I don't know why but without applying the modifier it was disconnected as per photo.